# Large number of errors in the console in android studio

Tags: android

Help me, I have installed android studio, but I can not write code, the IDE does not allow me, but the console writes a lot of errors, maybe someone has faced with this problem, please help,
p.s.: I live in russia, and the program only runs through a VPN
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLaEO.png)

Answer (score -1):

Starting with Android Studio Chipmunk, if you're seeing `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: view_tree_saved_state_registry_owner` or `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.savedstate.R$id` in the issues panel, make sure to include a `debugImplementation` dependency to `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate` in your module.

If you're seeing `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: view_tree_lifecycle_owner` in the issues panel, make sure to include a debugImplementation dependency to `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime` in your module.

If you're seeing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class androidx.customview.poolingcontainer.PoolingContainer` or `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/customview/poolingcontainer/PoolingContainerListener` in the issues panel, make sure to include a `debugImplementation` dependency to `androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer` in your module.

Comment: Where can I find it, and how do I fix it?